Your apps are affected by Google Play's target API level requirements
I have received this email for my 6 apps on Google Console
This email requires:

Updation of project to newer Android version
Updating the target SDK

Could anyone be able to answer? If I update my target SDK, Will it affect app performance or code?
6 of your apps are affected by Google Play's target API-level requirements
We've detected that 6 of your apps are targeting an old version of Android. To provide users a safe and secure experience, Google Play requires all apps to meet target API level requirements before Aug 31, 2024.
Action required
Update the following apps to target the latest Android version
Above is the email

Updating your target SDK to meet Google Play's requirements is essential to ensure your app remains available on the Play Store. Here’s how you can approach this update and what you need to consider:
Update targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion:

Open your build.gradle file (Module: app) and update the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to the latest version available. For example:
android {
     compileSdkVersion 34 // Replace with the latest version
     defaultConfig {
         targetSdkVersion 34 // Replace with the latest version
     }
}


Update Dependencies:
Ensure all your dependencies are compatible with the new target SDK. This might involve updating some libraries to their latest versions.
Test Thoroughly:

After updating, thoroughly test your app on various devices and Android versions to ensure there are no compatibility issues.


Behavior Changes:

Each new Android version introduces behavior changes that might affect your app. Review the behavior changes for the version you are targeting and update your code accordingly.

Deprecated APIs: Some APIs might be deprecated or removed in newer SDK versions. You will need to update your code to use the newer APIs.
Permission Changes:

Newer Android versions have more stringent permission requirements. Make sure your app handles runtime permissions correctly. This includes updating your AndroidManifest.xml and handling permissions in your code.
Performance Impact:

Generally, targeting a newer SDK should not negatively impact app performance. In fact, it can lead to performance improvements as you get access to the latest optimizations and features of the Android platform.


